# Insert Data from form to Access database

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007

I have a problem when i m doing a connection to access then error is occured Could not find file 'C:\Users\Geeta\Desktop\test1.mdb'. and mycode is :

```
protected void btn_submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
    // TODO: Modify the connection string and include any
    // additional required properties for your database.
    conn.ConnectionString = (@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data source= C:\Users\Geeta\Desktop\test1.mdb"); 


    conn.Open();
    string query = "insert into test (First Name,Address,Email,Password) values ('" + txt_fstname.Text + "','" + txt_email.Text + "', '"+txt_pass.Text+"', '"+txt_add.Text+"')";
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query,conn);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
    Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");

}
```

plz help me.

"Thanks"

Comment: Um, I hate to ask the obvious, but is does the file `'C:\Users\Geeta\Desktop\test1.mdb'` exist?

Comment: If the file is there and still getting the same error, then check the permissions for access to file. If still unsolved, update your post with full error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following connection string:

```
conn.ConnectionString = (@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data source=C:\Users\Geeta\Desktop\test1.mdb;");
```

Remark:

- There is no blank between = and the database
- The database path must end with a ;

Additionally:

- It seems that you try to access the database using ASP.NET. Please keep in mind, that the user that runs the website has not necessarily the permission to edit the database.